# TryParse in one line: accepted challenge?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Just a challenge I guess, but I hope to use TryParse in just one line :) My code:

```
DateTime tempDate;
user.DataNascita = DateTime.TryParse(txtDataDiNascita.Text, out tempDate) ? tempDate : (DateTime?)null;
```

`user.DataNascita` is `DateTime?`, and I want to return the data if TryParse is correct, null otherwise. But I need the out one (so, new line). Can't I have all in one line?

Just curious...

Comment: Sure: put the two lines inside a separate method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm usually using this extension method in LINQ queries:

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDate(this string dateString, string format = null)
{
    DateTime dt;
    bool success = format == null ? DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out dt) : DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, format, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
    return success ? dt : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

You use it in this way:

```
user.DataNascita = txtDataDiNascita.Text.TryGetDate();
```

Here's another overload with multiple formats and an `IFormatProvider`(different cultures):

```
public static DateTime? TryGetDate(this string dateString, IFormatProvider provider, params string[] formats)
{
    DateTime dt;
    var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, provider, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
    return success ? dt : (DateTime?)null;
}
```

Comment: +1 for handling formats.

Comment: content matters, who did. never. :)

Comment: Looks nice, but using `txtDataDiNascita.Text.TryGetDate()` .NET says that string does not contain a definition of TryGetDate? (I put that method in another Class, a sort of CommonUtils class)

Comment: @markzzz: It is an extension method, that means you have to put it in a static class like `public static class StringExtensions`

Answer (score 10):

You'd need a helper method, basically. For example:

```
public static DateTime? TryParseDateTime(string text)
{
    DateTime validDate;
    return DateTime.TryParse(text, out validDate) ? validDate : (DateTime?) null;
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
user.DataNascita = ParseHelpers.TryParseDateTime(txtDataDiNascita.Text);
```

You'd probably want overloads corresponding with the overloads of `DateTime.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParseExact`, too. I wouldn't personally make this an extension method as per Tim's answer, but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: +1 for simplicity.but Tim answer is more accurate.

Comment: unnecessarily accurate

Comment: @joshua: Not sure what you mean by "more accurate". What's inaccurate in my answer?

Comment: @JonSkeet Tim answer is more generic. it also handles the formats. there is no inaccuracy in your answer. who am i to say 618k rep's answer wrong.

Answer (score 4):

yea it's easy I didn't find this much of a challenge

```
DateTime temp; if (DateTime.TryParse(txtDataDiNascita.Text, out temp)) user.DataNascita = temp;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime tempDate; user.DataNascita= DateTime.TryParse(txtDataDiNascita.Text, out tempDate) ? tempDate : (DateTime?)null;
```

You could do it in a single line as above. but creating your helper method is good approach.